# Toggle div height to auto (100%) and return to defined?

Tags: php, jquery, toggle

I'm building movie review site using WordPress, I'm not so good with jquery or javascript, with php I can "fight".
I would need some help from you guys.
This is first question I actually couldn't find answer on stackoverflow, and I need it badly.

I have this code:

```
<div class="movie_cast">
<span class="movie_cast_bold">Cast: </span>John Hurt, Peter Mullan, Ingrid Bolsø Berdal, Ian Whyte, Robert Whitelock
</div>
```

My css is:

```
.movie_cast {
float: right;
width: 35%;
margin-left: 2%;
line-height: 15px;
font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
height: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Whats some simple jquery with button that I can toggle my cast from `height: 20px` to full height `height: auto`, and also return after clicked back.
With height of 20px it should show "more", and with full or auto height it would show "less" and return to height of 20 px.

Comment: you can use the animate function of jquery to target your cast to grow in size.

Comment: do you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/shE58/19/

Comment: Yes, Mohit Arora, like that, just with button on the right instead of clicking on text.

Comment: check demo in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
       var cssht = $('.movie_cast').height();
       if(cssht=='20')
           $('.movie_cast').height('auto');
        else
            $('.movie_cast').height('20px');
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/3edtrnqz/4/)**